# Everything in Firefox scaled up except the Window title font

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, hdpi

How can I get a reasonably scaled Firefox?

My Firefox looks like
[image: A wasteful firefox layout]

Everything but the title seems to be scaled up. Regular gtk apps behaves nicely. Java applications has a similar title bar but can mostly be fixed with plaf.

This is a hidpi screen that is used in a single, double and triple display setup. I have configured the resolution of the display to be readable without hidpi tweaks. 1600x900px. I have attempted and given up to get any of Wayland or X to work in a hidpi + other regular monitors setup. I think it is these attempts that led me here.

If I create a new user on this 17.10 I get a normal looking Firefox.

One other previous complication I can recall is that I had at one time installed the gnome-shell flat-remix theme.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Are you using Firefox's zoom function? (e.g. CTRL+ "+" zooms in, CTRL+ "-" zooms out, CTRL + 0 resets the zoom to 100%).

Comment: Yes, I regularly need to scale it down. I'm typing this on 50% Zoom. The stack.Imgur upload only got usable at 40% zoom. Please note that the Tabs, address bar and also the context/right-click menus are too big.